# DropDownListFor<> not using my selected value if I change it in the model before call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Why does `DropDownListFor<>` not always set the selected value?

In my case I've noticed this to happen when the dropdown list is being constructed after a form post and the value differs from the value that was submitted.

So the scenario is a form containing a dropdown to select a category you want to see. When you submit this, the dropdown is rebuilt as part of the results, and is preselected to the one you chose.

However, if the controller action changes the value that was posted and then passes that modified model to the view, the value in the model is ignored and no options are set as selected.

Even if you construct the `DropDownListFor<>` to specifically set the selected value, no option is set as selected.

When you don't change the submitted value in the model prior to going into the view, the following is all you need:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Selection.CategoryId,
                           new SelectList(Model.Categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id, Text = c.Name + " (" + c.Id + ")" }), "Value", "Text"),  
                            "All",                             
                            new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

But with the problem present (modifying the submitted value in the controller action), even the following ways of specifically setting the selected option does not work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Selection.CategoryId,
                           new SelectList(Model.Categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id, Text = c.Name + " (" + c.Id + ")" }), "Value", "Text", Model.Selection.CategoryId),  
                            "All",                             
                            new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Selection.CategoryId,
                           new SelectList(Model.Categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Id, Text = c.Name + " (" + c.Id + ")", Selected = c.Id == Model.Selection.CategoryId }), "Value", "Text"),  
                            "All",                             
                            new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't about `DropDownListFor` method, it is about model binding. When you return another view after a POST request, ASP.NET MVC thinks that the validation has failed and uses the previous values for model binding. You can read more about this behavior in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx).

You can prevent this by clearing ModelState in your action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    //return View(model); 
}
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks a bunch, I was pulling my hair out a little there.